# $X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in distribution iff $E\{f(X_{n})\} \to E\{f(X)\}$ for all bounded $ f \in C^{\infty}$.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$, $X$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables. Show that $X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in distribution iff $E\{f(X_{n})\}$ converges to $ E\{f(X)\}$ for all bounded $C^{\infty}$ functions $f$.

I have sufficiency: if $f$ is in $C^{\infty, b}$, and if $\lim_{n \to \infty} E\{f(X_{n})\}=E\{f(X)\}$, then by a theorem in the text, we have $X_{n}\to^{\mathcal{d}} X$.

For necessity, I am thinking that I should use the Monotone Class Theorem (Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a class of bounded functions mapping $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is closed under multiplication . Let $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathcal{M})$. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a vector space of functions with $\mathcal{H}$ containing $\mathcal{M}$. Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ contains the constant functions and is such that whenever $(f_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence in   $\mathcal{H}$ such that $0\leq f_{1}\leq f_{2} \leq \cdots$, then if $f=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}$ is bounded, then $f$ is in $\mathcal{H}$. Then $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded,  $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions.) So, we want $\mathcal{H}$ to be $C^{b}$, and we want $f_{n}$ to be played by $C^{\infty,b}$.

I am not sure how to show this mathematically rigorously, however.

Also, as a hint, we were told to use the results of the two previous exercises:

1. Let $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$, $X$, $Y$ by $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables, all on the same space, and suppose that $X_{n}+\sigma Y$ converges in distribution to $X+\sigma Y$ for each fixed $\sigma >0$. Show that $X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in distribution.
2. Let $X, Y$ be independent r.v.'s on the same space with values in $\mathbb{R}$ and assume $Y$ is $N(0,1)$. Let $f$ be bounded continuous. Show that $E\{f(X+\sigma Y)\}=E\{f_{\sigma}(X)\}$ where $f_{\sigma}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)\exp(-\frac{1}{2}|z-x|^{2}/\sigma^{2})dz$. Show that 
   $f_{\sigma}$ is bounded and $C^{\infty}$.

I am not sure how these are supposed to help, though. Especially the part about choosing a variable that is $N(0,1)$ and independent to $X$.

Comment: This iff equivalence is part of the Portmanteau Theorem, you can look up related proofs.

Comment: Use [Skorohod representation theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod's_representation_theorem) for the necessity part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the assumption, we have for each positive $\sigma$ that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb E[f_\sigma(X_n)]=\mathbb E[f_\sigma(X)].$$
By the result of 2., the RHS is $\mathbb E[f(X+\sigma Y)]$.

*If we enlarge the probability space*, we can construct $Y$ in order to be independent of the sequence $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$, so still using the result, the LHS is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb E[f(X_n+\sigma Y)]$.

We conclude by 1.

Comment: This is also necessity. What about assuming that $X_{n}\to X$ and them showing that $E\{f(X_{n})\}\to E\{f(X)\}$?

Comment: What is the definition of weak convergence you have to use?

Comment: Never mind. I realized the other direction is pretty much trivial. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.